# Adding Image from Project Resources to be used in datagridview

Tags: c#, image, datagridview

I carry out a select command to my local database and retrieve the results. I store them in a list of objects.

```
public class Person
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public Image image_url { get; set; }
}

people.Add(new Person
{
    roster_id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]),
    name = reader["name"].ToString(),
    rating = Convert.ToInt32(reader["age"]),
    image_url = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(reader["image_url"].ToString(), Properties.Resources.Culture))
});
```

However, the `image_url` does not seem to work and I get the error `Cannot convert from object to string`. Each image file in the project resources is named like `firstname-lastname` so `image_url` essentially just contains that.

Comment: I get an error at "image_url =  new bitmap(Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(".... Have you tried to cast as Image?    image_url = new Bitmap((Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(

Comment: @AnyMoose I've just tried that now, not working...I've updated the question with the error.

Comment: My only guess is that reader is returning an object that cannot be converted to string. Try to debug and break point at the reader returning the image_url, make sure the object returned is correct.

Comment: `image_url = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(reader["image_url"].ToString());` This will work provided that the value return by `reader["image_url"]` is not DbNull. You should always check that the returned field value `!= DBNull.Value` before assigning it, anyway. Also, there must be an Object resource with that name (another check to perform).

Answer (score 0):

See the reference for GetObject method:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/963f81yd(v=vs.110).aspx

image_url = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(reader["image_url"].ToString(), Properties.Resources.Culture).ToString())

GetObject return an object value, that is the value that you might convert to string.

Comment: I am getting `An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in TestProgram.exe`

`Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: `.ToString()` on the `.GetObject()` method returned value shouldn't be there. You trying to create a Bitmap from a string.